# Inequality in the space of bounded linear operators in Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(a_n)_n$ be sequence of bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space $E$ and $b$ be a positive operator on $E$, Why
$$\left\|\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^da_n^*ba_n\right\|\leq\|b\|\left\|\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^da_n^*a_n\right\|\;??$$
Thank you for your help..

Comment: If you assume $b$ is a positive operator, then $a_n^*b a_n$ is positive. You've got:

$$\langle x,\sum_n a_n^* b a_n  x\rangle =\sum_n \langle a_n x, b a_nx\rangle≤\|b\|\,\sum_n\langle x,a_n^*a_nx\rangle  ≤\|b\|\,\left\|\sum a_n^*a_n\right\|\,\|x\|^2$$
Taking the supremum over $\|x\|=1$ gives the desired inequality. I think you might be able to start from this case and see the general case.

Comment: Thank you. I modify the question. Please write your comment as an answer in order to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $b$ is positive it follows that $a_n^* b a_n$ is positive. As a sum of positives $\sum a_n^* ba_n$ is positve. One can then see

$$\langle x, \sum_n a_n^* b a_nx \rangle  = \sum_n \langle a_n x, b a_nx \rangle ≤\|b\|\sum_n\langle a_n x,a_nx\rangle =\|b\|\,\langle x, \sum_n a_n^* a_n x\rangle ≤ \|b\|\ \left\|\sum_n a_n^*a_n\right\|\,\|x\|$$
Taking the supremum over $\|x\|=1$ gives you the desired inequality in the case that $b$ is positive.